# Ansible : Install a role package and run it

Tags: ansible, handler, role

I'm using Datadog for Ansible. I have a role which installs the Datadog package but doesn't run the datadog role automatically after the package installation.
Currently, we need in each project to call Datadog role manually.

```
- hosts: ...
roles :
- role1 (installing Datadog)
- Datadog.datadog
```

Is it possible to call Datadog role in my role1 instead of having to write "datadog.datadog" everywhere after role1. Precisely, can we execute a role after a task which is responsible to install this role ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: did you check the `meta`, you can add it as dependency

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies), Ansible provides role dependecies. 
You may create in `Datadog.datadog` role new directory named meta with main.yml file. In `meta/main.yml` write

```
--- 
dependencies:
    - { role: role1 }
```

After that, when you call `Datadog.datadog` role, Ansible will run `role1` automatically before `Datadog.datadog` role.

If you create another role named `Datadog.datadog1` with the same `meta/main.yml` file and call roles `Datadog.datadog` and `Datadog.datadog1`, then Ansible will run `role1` only once, before running Datadogs roles.